# Producer/Consumer multi-threaded code is not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

> Sharedresource class

```
    class Sharedresource {
        private int contents;
        private boolean available = false;

        public synchronized int get() {
            while (available == false) {
                // System.out.println("sharedresorce,while(false)");
                try {
                    // /System.out.println("sharedresorce,while(false)object block");
                    wait();
                    // System.out.println("sharedresorce,while(false)object relise");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
                }
            }
            available = false;
            notify();
            return contents;
        }

        public synchronized void set(int value) {
            while (available == true) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
                }
            }
            contents = value;
            available = true;
            notify();
        }
    }
```

> Produser class

```
    class Produser extends Thread {
        private Sharedresource resource;
        private int number;

        Produser(Sharedresource s, int number) {
            resource = s;
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                resource.set(i);
                System.out.println("produser#" + this.number + "set:" + i);
                // try{
                // sleep(2000);
                // }
                // catch (Exception e) {
                // System.out.println("tread intrupted");
                // }
            }
        }
    }
```

> consumer class

```
    class Consumer extends Thread {
        private Sharedresource resource;
        private int number;

        public Consumer(Sharedresource s, int number) {
            resource = s;
            this.number = number;
        }

        int value = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                value = resource.get();
                System.out.println("Consumer#" + this.number + "getvalue:" + value);

            }
        }
    }
```

> MAIN CLASS

```
    public class SynchronizatonDemo121 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Sharedresource r = new Sharedresource();
            Produser p = new Produser(r, 1);
            Consumer c = new Consumer(r, 1);
            p.start();
            c.start();

        }

    }
```

> output-1

```
Consumer#1getvalue:1
produser#1set:1
produser#1set:2
Consumer#1getvalue:2
produser#1set:3
Consumer#1getvalue:3
produser#1set:4
Consumer#1getvalue:4
produser#1set:5
Consumer#1getvalue:5
produser#1set:6
Consumer#1getvalue:6
Consumer#1getvalue:7
produser#1set:7
produser#1set:8
produser#1set:9
Consumer#1getvalue:8
Consumer#1getvalue:9
produser#1set:10
Consumer#1getvalue:10
```

> output-2

```
produser#1set:1
produser#1set:2
Consumer#1getvalue:1
Consumer#1getvalue:2
produser#1set:3
Consumer#1getvalue:3
produser#1set:4
Consumer#1getvalue:4
produser#1set:5
Consumer#1getvalue:5
produser#1set:6
Consumer#1getvalue:6
produser#1set:7
Consumer#1getvalue:7
produser#1set:8
Consumer#1getvalue:8
produser#1set:9
Consumer#1getvalue:9
produser#1set:10
Consumer#1getvalue:10
```

> output-3

```
produser#1set:1
Consumer#1getvalue:1
Consumer#1getvalue:2
produser#1set:2
produser#1set:3
Consumer#1getvalue:3
produser#1set:4
Consumer#1getvalue:4
produser#1set:5
Consumer#1getvalue:5
produser#1set:6
Consumer#1getvalue:6
Consumer#1getvalue:7
produser#1set:7
produser#1set:8
Consumer#1getvalue:8
Consumer#1getvalue:9
produser#1set:9
produser#1set:10
Consumer#1getvalue:10
```

my threads are not working properly as per the producer and consumers behavior.
I had attached my output over there for batter understanding so where is the problem in my code please verify me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your producer and consumer are producing and consuming the numbers in the expected order. However, the output is not synchronized, since you don't print it in synchronized methods, so you get a different order in each execution.

If you move your `println` statements to your synchronized `get` and `set` methods :

```
    public synchronized int get() {
        while (available == false) {
            // System.out.println("sharedresorce,while(false)");
            try {
                // /System.out.println("sharedresorce,while(false)object block");
                wait();
                // System.out.println("sharedresorce,while(false)object relise");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
            }
        }
        available = false;
        notify();
        System.out.println("Consumer#"  + "getvalue:" + contents);
        return contents;
    }

    public synchronized void set(int value) {
        while (available == true) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
            }
        }
        contents = value;
        available = true;
        System.out.println("produser#" + "set:" + value);
        notify();
    }
```

You'll get the expected output :

```
produser#set:1
Consumer#getvalue:1
produser#set:2
Consumer#getvalue:2
produser#set:3
Consumer#getvalue:3
produser#set:4
Consumer#getvalue:4
produser#set:5
Consumer#getvalue:5
produser#set:6
Consumer#getvalue:6
produser#set:7
Consumer#getvalue:7
produser#set:8
Consumer#getvalue:8
produser#set:9
Consumer#getvalue:9
produser#set:10
Consumer#getvalue:10
```

Comment: you mean in the before printing line threads release the lock and another threads starts working but I had checked with applying sleep methods before printing line then why another thread is waiting to complete the sleeping time why its not doing its work      below is the code sample

Comment: class Produser extends Thread {
 private Sharedresource resource;
 private int number;

 Produser(Sharedresource s, int number) {
  resource = s;
  this.number = number;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   resource.set(i);
   try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  System.out.println("produser#" + this.number + "set:" + i);

Comment: @sarvoday You can't rely on sleep time for synchronization. If you want the printing to be synchronized, it must be performed in synchronized methods/blocks. Your synchronization ensured that your threads performed their work in the correct order, but they didn't print their output in the correct order.